# How to concatenate datetime with timezone without change time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to concatenate

> date +' '+ time +'timezone'

without format datetime in selected timezone.
I'm using momentjs but when I do : 
currently: 
    `var dt= moment(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz(timezone).format()`

the date was converted to specific timezone.

All i just want is to concatenate datetime with timezone without change it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what it's actually doing right now?

Comment: The problem is, that just appending the time zone will change to actual time, if your local time zone is not Greenwich time. The offset of your local time will be added/substracted if you want to access the date the next time. Is that intended?

Comment: If you want to concatenate the time zone, use the string concatenation operator, `+`...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like below?

```js
var dt = moment(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
var tz = moment.tz.guess()
console.log(dt.toString() + " " + tz)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
moment(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z Z')
```

However according to the momentJs [docu](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) you also need the [moment-timezone addon](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Alternatively if you know the timezone, you could probably do something like

```
moment(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss [UTC] Z')
```